# Почему android studio подчёркивает переменную?

Tags: java, android-studio

myRad имеет тип float. Кто-нибудь знает, что нужно исправить? У меня есть другие переменные float, но они не подчёркнуты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При наведении на подчеркивание должна быть подсказка

Comment: Уверяю, никакие подсказки не предлагаются

Comment: Всё дело в этой строке. Если её убрать то подчёркивания убираются. [![введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAuWg.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAuWg.png)

Comment: Может нужно `2.0` присваивать? float же

Comment: @NikitaUmnov Нет, причина подчеркивания в другом, см. мой ответ (а на присвоение 2.0 будет ошибка, что это double, а не float).

Comment: Думаю, ошибки подчеркиваются красным. А это на ошибку не похоже. Тут должен быть другой смысл этого подчёркивания.

Answer (score 3):

Указывает на переназначенную переменную или параметр. Означает, что переменной было присвоено какое-то значение, а потом было присвоено другое (в вашем случае в строке `myRad /= 2;`), но первое значение нигде не использовалось. Это не ошибка по сути, поэтому никаких подсказок нет.

Цветовая схема для выделения ставится в настройках Settings - Editor - Color Scheme - Java.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Странно как-то, что нет никаких подсказок, не встречал такого в других IDE. Везде описано любое подчеркивание - хоть ошибка, хоть warning, хоть рекомендация или отклонение от стиля. Какой смысл подчеркивать и таинственно молчать)

Comment: @NikitaUmnov Видимо, потому что это подчеркивание происходит не из ошибки, а из оформления кода (так же как оформляются цветом и жирным шрифтом ключевые слова, но подсказок на них так же нет). Можно убрать подчеркивание и изменить на жирный шрифт и курсив или что-нибудь или вообще никак не выделято. Но я согласен, что если значение переменной изменяется без использвания, то можно было бы и предупредить. Хотя при компиляции это наверняка отловится и лишнее присваивание будет выкинуто.